# Openwhisk: Unable to obtain the API list

Tags: openwhisk

I setup Apache Openwhisk locally following this guide: http://jamesthom.as/blog/2018/01/19/starting-openwhisk-in-sixty-seconds/. In general it seems to work correctly, but whenever I'm trying to execute any commands related to api, e.g.

```
wsk -i api list
```

it gives me an error,

```
Unable to obtain the API list: The requested resource does not exist. (code 153)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately a temporary issue with docker-compose, and work is in progress to fix this.

Comment: Issue is here to follow progress https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk-devtools/issues/2